# Compare byte[i] with string In java

Tags: java

I have string like this

```
String text = "f001050000000000003d61c1c1df400200c0000009181600ef014000003f20"
```

I converted it to bytes to loop through it as bytes

```
byte[] bytes = new BigInteger(text,16).toByteArray();        
    for (int i = 1; i < bytes.length; i++) 
    {            
        System.out.print(String.format("%02x ", bytes[i]));
    }
```

I want to compare byte value of i `bytes[i]` with equivalent string 
something like that

```
for (int i = 1; i < bytes.length; i++) 
    {      
        if (bytes[i] == "f0")
        {
            break;
        }
        System.out.print(String.format("%02x ", bytes[i]));
    }
```

This will not work for sure, but how can I do this compare

Comment: There's a critical subtlety here: Do you want each two-character portion of the string converted to a byte, eg the first two characters of "text" would yield the *byte* value 0xF0, or are you wanting the byte value of the *characters* "F0"?

Comment: @David W I want the byte value of f0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bytes[i] == "f0"`  is always false because you compare the value of a `byte` to a reference of a `String`

Change your condition to

```
(bytes[i] & 0xFF) == 0xF0
```

`&oxFF` because this way we mask the byte and make an `int` compare.
This way the condition will be true for `bytes[i] == -16` which has the bit representation of `0xF0`.

Changed the code referring to comment of *@isvforall*

Comment: `0xf0` - will out of range

Comment: `(bytes[i] & 0xFF) == 0xF0` - will be `false`

Comment: @isvforall: its `true` for `bytes[i]=-16`. I made a test-loop over the whole byte value range and it is `true` for byte value -16. Here is my [test](http://sharetext.org/vAlc)

Answer (score 3):

`byte` is a numeric type, so you can simply do

```
if(bytes[i] == (byte)0xf0) { ... }
```

Comment: it works good will all bytes but it did not work with the first byte 0xf0 of the string

Comment: `0xf0` - will out of range

Comment: So, how we can compare `f0` ?

Comment: Well, your loop condition is starting at `i=1`, not `i=0`. So, of course it will skip the first byte.

Comment: @HaithamSakr yes, then you should use `int` instead of `byte`

Comment: This another problem, when the loop begin with `0` it adds a `00` before the actual first byte!
It ignores `f0`

Comment: @HaithamSakr: that would be a separate issue, I think.